# JavaScript for Changing width of DiV element using range slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, drawing

I'm trying to do a html5 canvas drawing app and i can't figure out how to change de line width for the shapes using a range slider.
PLease help me with the javascript or tell me where i'm wrong

This is what i tried in JS:

```
function change_width(element) {
    lineWidth = element.innerHTML
  }
```

Comment: Changing the content of a (global?) variable doesn't change the content of the canvas. Please add a [mcve] of your setup.

Answer (score 0):

In the inline version which works you use the value of the element.

In the other version you have used innerHTML.

Try using element.value instead.

Comment: Thanks! i tried but i don t know why it s not working..

Answer (score -1):

Rather than the naive inline event handlers used you could quite easily use a single external event listener to process each input that you use to control the properties of the canvas. If you were to assign each DOM element a dataset attribute that relates to the property to be modified/monitored you could assign these to the global `window` object at page load and update these window properties when the value of the `input` element changes.

The below code simply prints the name and value to the console but you would likely use a callback to redraw the canvas to reflect the variable changes?!

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[data-attr]').forEach(input=>{
  window[ input.dataset.attr ]=0;
  
  input.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    window[ this.dataset.attr ]=this.value;
    console.info('attr:%s value:%s',this.dataset.attr,window[ this.dataset.attr ])
  })
  
  
});
```

```html
<div id="toolbar2">

    <input data-attr="fillColor" type="color" class="color-picker" />
    <input data-attr="strokeColor" type="color" class="color-picker" />
    <input data-attr="lineWidth" type="range" min="1" max="50" class="pen-range" />
    <input data-attr="opacity" type="range" min="1" max="50" class="pen-range" />
    
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to pollute the global scope with variables? And how does adding global variables solve OPs problem?

Comment: That was a `for-instance` - could just as easily assign directly to the canvas. The Op's problem with the function `change_width` was the use of `innerHTMl` rather than value and I rather think that the `polluting the global scope` with a few variables is neither here nor there personally